# Replacing apostrophe's and white spaces in entire column in R

Tags: r, replace

I have a dataframe with factor columns that represent the heights and wingspans of athletes. I am trying to change the format of wingspan from ex. 5' 10.5" to something like 5.105 and 6' 1" to 6.01 for the sake of accurate graphing. If there is a way to do this, please let me know :) Thank you for your time!

I have tried replace() and str_replace_all() but it does not work. I also have the measurements in the form of 6. 6.5  and 6. 11.5, however, you can probably see how R would assume that the former is a longer wingspan than the latter. That is my problem.

Here is my code:

```
#playerphysicals is a dataframe of factors that contains various physiological measurements of 1328 NBA athletes.
    playerphysicals1<- tibble(playerphysicals=c("5' 10.5\"", "6' 1\""))
    out <- playerphysicals %>% 
      mutate(first = as.numeric(str_extract(playerphysicals$Wingspan, "[^\']+")), 
             second = str_extract(playerphysicals$Wingspan, '[\\d\\.]+\"$'),
             second = as.numeric(str_replace(second, "\"", ""))/100, 
             x_num = first + second) %>% 
      select(-first, -second) %>%
      as.data.frame
    out

    #output
    x_num
    <dbl>
     NA
     NA
     NA
```

Comment: Can you show all patterns and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this.  First, you could split up the first number from the second, remove the double-quote from the second term and turn them both into numbers.  You would then divide the second number by 100 and add it to the first.

```
library(tibble)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(x=c("5' 10.5\"", "6' 1\""))
out <- df %>% 
  mutate(first = as.numeric(str_extract(x, "[^\']+")), 
         second = str_extract(x, '[\\d\\.]+\"$'),
         second = as.numeric(str_replace(second, "\"", ""))/100, 
         x_num = first + second) %>% 
  select(-first, -second) %>%
  as.data.frame
out
#          x x_num
# 1 5' 10.5" 5.105
# 2    6' 1" 6.010
```

---

**EDIT** - add in actual data frame structure

In answer to the comments, here is it using the OP's data.  I had to modify a bit.  I made the data set name `playerphysicals` and the variable name `Wingspan`.  Note that inside the `dplyr` functions, you don't need to call the variable with `data$variable`, you can just used the variable name because the data are being implicitly called in the function through the pip (`%>%`).

```
playerphysicals <- tibble(Wingspan=c("5' 10.5\"", "6' 1\""))
playerphysicals
# # A tibble: 2 x 1
#   Wingspan   
#   <chr>      
# 1 "5' 10.5\""
# 2 "6' 1\""   

out <- playerphysicals %>% 
  mutate(first = as.numeric(str_extract(Wingspan, "[^\']+")), 
         second = str_extract(Wingspan, '[\\d\\.]+\"$'),
         second = as.numeric(str_replace(second, "\"", ""))/100, 
         Wingspan_num = first + second) %>% 
  select(-first, -second) %>%
  as.data.frame
out
#   Wingspan Wingspan_num
# 1 5' 10.5"        5.105
# 2    6' 1"        6.010
```

Comment: Hi Dave, this seemed to work. As I am new to R, I will now ask a basic question. How can I apply this not only to the 2 values provided ("5' 10.5", "6' 1") but to the entire column? Thank you1

Comment: @NickA let's say you've got a dataset called `my_data` with a variable called `z` that has all of these string.  You just need to replace `out <- df` with `out <- my_data` and replace `x` - the first argument to `str_extract()` in the next two lines with `z` the name of your variable that has all of the strings.

Comment: Ok we are making progress! However, now my entire new column is filled with NA.

Comment: Without seeing your data, it’s hard to troubleshoot. Can you edit your question and post the actual dataset.

Comment: @NickA OK, I edited the answer to include this new data structure with a couple of small edits.

Comment: I have copied your exact code Dave and I still receive NA's. Very interesting problem here..

Comment: @NickA do you get any warnings or errors in the output?

Comment: Nope! It creates a new table called out which includes all of my original playerphysicals data plus the Wingspan_num column which holds all NA's

Comment: @NickA could you email me the actual data you are using?  dave@quantoid.net.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
test <- structure(list(my_column = c("5' 10.5\"", "6' 1\"")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                           -2L))

test$my_column <- gsub(pattern = "'", replacement = '', test$my_column) # replace ' by nothing
test$my_column <- gsub(pattern = "\"", replacement = '', test$my_column) # replace " by nothing
test$my_column <- gsub(pattern = " ", replacement = '', test$my_column) # replace space by nothing
```